# $g \colon [0,1] \to [0,1]$ be a continuous map and consider the iteration $x_{n+1}=g(x_n)$.

Tags: numerical-methods

I came across the following problem:

> Let $g \colon [0,1] \to [0,1]$ be a continuous map and  consider the iteration $x_{n+1}=g(x_n)$.Then Which of the following maps will yield a fixed point for $g$?
>
> The *options* are as follows:
> a. $g(x)=\frac{x^2}{4}$,
> b. $g(x)=\frac{x^2}{32}$,
> c. $g(x)=\frac{x^2}{8}$,
> d. $g(x)=\frac{x^2}{16}$.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is certainly *all of them*, according to a very general and powerful theorem called [the Brower fixed point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem).  You'll probably get some funny looks if you turn that in, though, as I think it's quite a bit easier than that.

Don't all the maps have an obvious common fixed point?  Is that really the whole problem?

Comment: The question is not about the existence of a fixed point, which as you say is obvious, but whether the iteration of $g$ gets to it, I guess from any starting point. Perhaps you mean Banach's fixed-point theorem.

Comment: @lhf Perhaps, that's what the question is *supposed* to be.

Answer (score 2):

Graph each of these functions in a square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$. A fixed point is exactly where the graph crosses the diagonal of the square. Where does this happen for each function?

Alternately, in the vein of using too-powerful technology, since $[0,1]$ is a complete metric space, you can use the [contraction mapping theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping_theorem) (bearing in mind that differentiable functions on compact spaces are globally Lipschitz, with global Lipschitz constant the maximum of the derivative.)